# JavaScript: Rotate Polys

Tags: javascript

My code doesn't work right:

```
function rotate(Points, Angle) {
    for (var i=0; i<Points.length;i++) {
        Points[i] = [Math.cos(Angle) * Points[i][0] - Math.sin(Angle) * Points[i][1], Math.sin(Angle) * Points[i][0] + Math.cos(Angle) * Points[i][1]];
    }
    return Points;
}


rotate([[0, 0], [50, 0], [25, 25]], 5);
```

I used the following: http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_rotate_polygon_points.html

Comment: Define : "My code doesn't work right:"

Comment: Can you point out what's wrong?

Comment: The polys rotate, but the angle seems to be random xD?!

Comment: Downvoted for not pasting in the real code, and for not saying what "doesn't work right" means.

Comment: Perhaps he doesn't know why it's not working Jonathan.

Comment: The problem is not that he "doesn't know why it's not working." The problem is that he doesn't say what "not working means". Does it throw an exception? Does it crash his braille device driver? Does it give the wrong answer?

Comment: Jonathan, if you bothered to read the comment thread, you'd have noticed that the problem is described in the comment previous to yours.  Besides, a little patience is probably warranted with newer members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cos` and `sin` in most programming languages are in radians. Are you sure you want to rotate by 5 radians (= 286 degrees)?

Comment: Oh, that could be the problem.
I want to rotate by 5 degrees.
How could I rotate by degrees?

Comment: 1 degree = 1 radian * 180/π.

Therefore, `rotate(..., 5 * Math.PI/180);`

Comment: Math.sin() expects radians you cannot switch to degrees, btw it would be a goog idea to calculate sin and cos only once and assign their values to variables to resuse them